# AppDelegate method not called after force terminating

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I'm trying to figure out how AppDelegate methods work.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        print("didFinishLaunchingWithOptions")
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        print("willResignActive")
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        print("didEnterBackground")
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        print("willEnterForeground")
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        print("didbecomeActive")
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        print("willTerminate")
    }
}
```

It seems working as expected when launching the app first time.
But once forcibly terminate the app, these methods will be not called at all after that.

Is there a way to call these methods after forcibly terminating the app?

- xcode 9.2
- swift4
- ios11.2 on simulator

Comment: Connection terminate when you close app. So that methods in app-delegate not called.

Answer (score 1):

At least `func application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)` is always called when an app starts. What makes you think it isn't?

Please note that after you've forcibly terminated a running app, the debugger connection you might have is terminated, and a newly started app does not automatically reconnect to your debugger.

Comment: Because print debug is not output even if it restarts after forcibly terminating.

But I first heard about Debugger Connection.